# Лайки на Ajax и Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, django

Пытаюсь реализовать лайки на сайте через ajax. При нажатии лайка что-то происходит с url и подключение к серверу не происходит. Выдает `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/%7B%%20url%20'like_url'%20%%7D 404 (Not Found)`

**Post.js**

```
$(".like").on("click", function(){

    console.log("hit");

    var pk = $(this).attr("name")

    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'like_url' %}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'post_id': pk,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(response){
            $("i").toggleClass("like_active");
        },
        error: function(rs, e) {
            alert(rs.responseText); 
        }
    });
});
```

**Template.html**

```
<div class="likes">
 <a class="like" name="{{ post.id }}">
  {% if user in post.likes.all %}
    <i class="fas fa-heart like_active"></i>
  {% else %}
     <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
  {% endif %}
 </a>
 <span class="likes_num">{{ post.likes.count }}</span>
</div>
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:post_id>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('post/<int:post_id>/like/', views.like, name='like'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь отрендерить урлу внутри **.JS** файла.
Решить эту проблему можно путем объявления урлы глобально на окно в HTML файле:

```
<script>
    window.like_url = "{% url 'like' post.id %}"
</script>
```

Потом уже в **.JS** получаем урлу через `window.like_url`